# How to rotate the signature in the react-signature-canvas package

Tags: reactjs, canvas, digital-signature, rotatetransform

I have implemented react-signature-canvas package in my react project. Is there a way to rotate the signature?

the documentation (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-signature-canvas) doesn't provide any option to rotate the signature. is there a way to do this?